# Splitting a long string in pandas cell near the n-th character position into multiple cells without splitting words

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, pandas

As MS Excel limits the number of characters in a cell to 32767, I have to split longer strings in a pandas dataframe into several cells.

Is there a way to split the strings of a pandas column "Text" into several columns "Text_1", "Text_2", "Text_3", ... to divide? It is also important that the text block is not separated within a word, so I assume regex is needed.

An example dataframe:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'Text' : ['This should be the first very long string','This is the second very long string','This is the third very long string','This is the last string which is very long'],
               'Date' : [2019, 2018, 2019, 2018],
               'Source' : ["FAZ", "SZ" , "HB", "HB"],
               'ID' : ["ID_1", "ID_2", "ID_3", "ID_4"]})
df_test

    Text                                        Date    Source  ID
0   This should be the first very long string   2019    FAZ     ID_1
1   This is the second very long string         2018    SZ      ID_2
2   This is the third very long string          2019    HB      ID_3
3   This is the last string which is very long  2018    HB      ID_4
```

Assuming that the cut in this example occurs at `n=15` and not at `n=32767`, I want to split the Text column accordingly to something like this:

```
    Text_1          Text_2          Text_3         Text_4      Date   Source    ID
0   This should be  the first very  long string                2019   FAZ       ID_1
1   This is the     second very     long string                2018   SZ        ID_2
2   This is the     third very long  string                    2019   HB        ID_3
3   This is the     last string     which is very  long        2018   HB        ID_4
```

Ultimately the approach should be scalable to `n=32767` and at least ten new columns `"Text_1"`, `"Text_2"`, and so on.

So far I have created a new column `"n"` indicating the length of the `df_text["Text"]` strings per row:

```
df_test['n'] = df_test['Text'].str.split("").str.len()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the general idea.

```
# find longest long string, then divide the text 
# into the number of new cols you want, adding a | at
# the division and then later splitting by that |

longest = ""
for x in df_test['Text']:
    if len(x) > len(longest):
        longest = x
    continue

import math 

num_cols = math.floor(len(longest.split(' ')) / 3) # shoot for 3 words per row
for index,row in df_test.iterrows():

    word_str = row['Text']
    word_char_len = len(word_str)
    word_as_list = word_str.split(' ')
    num_words = len(word_as_list)

    col_index = math.ceil(len(word_as_list) / num_cols)

    for _ in range(num_cols - 1):
        word_as_list.insert(col_index,'|')
        col_index += col_index
    new = ' '.join(word_as_list)
    df_test.at[index,'Text'] = new

cols = ['Text'+str(i) for i in range(1,num_cols+1)]
df_test[cols] = df_test.Text.str.split('|',expand=True)
del df_test['Text']                                                                                                                   
print(df_test)
```

OUTPUT

```
   Date Source    ID            Text1          Text2                Text3
0  2019    FAZ  ID_1  This should be      the first      very long string
1  2018     SZ  ID_2     This is the    second very           long string
2  2019     HB  ID_3     This is the     third very           long string
3  2018     HB  ID_4     This is the    last string    which is very long
```

I will upload a full one when I am done. Comment if you don't like this way or have other suggestions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this nice solution! It’s working totally fine if I know the number of columns to be created from the long string. In my case I am only aware of the maximum characters one cell should contain (32767). So I am looking for a possibility which is scalable according to the number of text blocks created from the long string, with each containing nearly 32767 characters.

Comment: No problem @Peet, happy to help. Can you provide another description of the maximum char length of each cell? Does this mean that a single element in a dataframe column has a maximum character length of 32767?

Comment: @Peet I have an edit to make. To find the longest str in the 'Text' column you can do  longest = df.loc[df['Text'].str.len().idxmax(), Text] instead of what I did earlier. I just tested it and it is slighlty more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - a single pandas cell should contain a maximum number of characters of 32767. So the string from df_test[“Text”] should be split accordingly.